# Updating Records In a Second Table Using Foreign Keys

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, foreign-keys, sql-update, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a database in which two tables have a 1:1 relationship using foreign keys.  Table one is called Manifest and table two is called Inventory.  When an inventory record is added using the application this is built for it uses a foreign key to reference the matching record in the manifest table.  In addition, this causes an update to a column in the manifest table for the matching record called Received (datatype: `BIT`) to 1.  This is used for reconciliation and reporting purposes.

Now here is where it gets tricky:  This database is synchronized to a server database using Sync Framework in a client-server relationship.  The Manifest table is synchronized in one direction from server to client, and the Inventory table is synchronized from client to server.  Because of this the "received" column in the Manifest table is not always updated accurately on the server-side after a sync.

I was thinking of creating a stored procedure to perform this update, but I'm a bit rusty on my SQL (and T-SQL).  The SP I was thinking of using would use a `CURSOR` to locate any records in the inventory table where the foreign key is `NOT NULL` (this is allowed due to exceptions where we receive something that was not in the manifest).  The cursor would then allow me to iterate though all the records to locate the matching record in the manifest table and update the "received" column.  I know that this cannot be the best way to perform this update.  Can anyone suggest another way of doing this that would be faster and use less resources?  Examples would be appreciated =)

Comment: Look into using a trigger.  I dont know how it acts with the "Sync Framework" but I would suspect it should work.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the suggestion.  The Sync Framework automatically generates a lot of triggers when applied to a database.  I've read that adding additional custom triggers can cause conflicts and fire at inappropriate times, but I think I need to do some additional research on that idea.

Comment: I was afraid of that but if you can test it first, it really is the BEST way to solve your issue, without having to change any of your existing code (which I like).